# swift iPad Table View not Transparent

Tags: ipad, swift, tableview, transparent

In swift, I have a UI Table View and I have the background set as clear for a transparent background, and for the iPhone it works perfectly. But for iPad, it does not, it has a white background, not clear. I saw an answer, but it wasn't for swift, but that didn't work either. 
My code for the iPhone is:

```
tableview.backgroundcolor = UIColor.clearcolor()
```

I tried adding:

```
tableview.background = nil
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: probably your iPad cells' background colour is `whiteColor` as default and that is why you can't see them translucent.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. It seems that somewhere in the process of adding a UITableView to the window (between willMoveToWindow and didMoveToWindow), some iPad's reset the backgroundColor of the table view to white. It does this covertly without using the backgroundColor property.

I now use this as a base class in place of UITableView when I need a colored/transparent table...

```
class ColorableTableView : UITableView {
    var _backgroundColor:UIColor?
    override var backgroundColor:UIColor? {
        didSet {
            _backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        }
    }
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        backgroundColor = _backgroundColor
        super.didMoveToWindow()
    }
}
```

EDIT: Cells also have their backgroundColor's set to white on my iPad in the same way (i.e. those that are in the table during the move to the window), so the same applies to them, lest you end up with the odd opaque cell popping up from time to time as it is reused ...

```
class ColorableTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    var _backgroundColor:UIColor?
    override var backgroundColor:UIColor? {
        didSet {
            _backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        }
    }
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        backgroundColor = _backgroundColor
        super.didMoveToWindow()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you inserting that code? I had a similar problem recently with a tableview that I had subclassed. Setting the background color to clear worked perfectly well in the subclass for iPhone but on iPad it was still displaying as white.

My solution was that I had to also put it in the viewWillAppear function on the specific tableViewController that contained the table.

```
// myTableViewController
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor .clearColor()
}
```