# Container View White Background, iPad Swift Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My problem only occurs on iPad. By default, my container view is clear/transparent. It works and appears fine on iPhone but when displaying on iPad it defaults to a white background. The issue is the same on most custom uitableviews as well.

I've attached an image of the problem below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was basically a solution to my problem, only thing I had to add and I will attach the swift code was "willDisplayCell" method using tableViewDelegate.

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var backgroundView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.backgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }`

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with cell's background color on iPad. I'd faced with this problem.

I've fixed this problem by changing background color of all components of cells to the clear color  in code.

```
//in cell's awakeFromNib
UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundView = backgroundView;

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901394/uitableview-uitableviewcell-challenge-with-transparent-background-on-ipad-with) is very helpful

Comment: This was basically a solution to my problem, only thing I had to add and I will attach the swift code was "willDisplayCell" method using tableViewDelegate.

Check out the OP for the solution.

Comment: I think, using of cellWillAppear method is good solution :). But I don't use it because it is called for one cell many times (every time when the cell disappeared and appeared), and each time UIView is Allocated. I prefer of using custom class for every type of cells in my apps and override awakeFromNib or initWith... methods to configure custom parametres.

Answer (score 0):

The Default colour for cell's `ContentView` is different for `iPhone` and `iPad`.

You have to set `Background colour of Cell's ContentView` in your Storyboard and you are done.

Comment: have to changed background color for Cell and it's content view both?

Comment: I fixed it with willDisplayCell method then altering from that point onward.