# Odd behaviour when using UITableView in a UIViewController that is presented Modally

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have discovered an odd behaviour when putting a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` that is presented Modally (Formsheet)

> **Fixed due to a coding error**: For some reasons the table view is showing 2 sets of labels in each
>   cell when only 1 is set up. The first set shows the original Labels
>   name then directly over top is the coded text. See iPhone4s screen
>   shot.

On the iPad the table view is white even though the table, cells and contentView has been set to clearColor. see iPad screen shot.

iPad screen shot:

[image]

iPhone screen shot:

[image]

This is a test code to see if it was an error in my coding in my main app.

```
class TestTableView:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var testTable: UITableView!
var data = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.testTable.delegate = self
    self.testTable.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println(self.data.count)
    return self.data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! testTableCell
    cell.testTableCell!.text = self.data[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}

class testTableCell:UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var testTableCell: UILabel!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
}
```

Something interesting is that the println(self.data.count) prints out 4 times.

Can anyone see a problem in my code? Or is this a bug?

Any feedback would be helpful..

Comment: You should use `cell.testTableCell.text = xxx` rather than `cell.textLabel!.text = xxx`.

Comment: When running the app in the simulator, hit the Debug View Hierarchy button in Xcode under the code editor. This will allow you to see your interface in layers. Perhaps you have one or more of the controls duplicate or something...

Comment: @Bannings. Feel a little foolish for missing that. The damn autocomplete foiled me. Haha. However the issue still remains that on the ipad the background of the table is still White. any ideas?

Comment: The table in both screen shots is considerably narrower than the presented view. Why? What _is_ the presented view? (The purple thing....) Clearly it isn't the table, so what's actually being presented? You need to explain much more about what the architecture is here. Your info is way too skimpy to reproduce this.

Comment: As I said in the description the view is presented modally (formsheet).The view has a purple background and the table is constrained with a large margin around it. Testing is on iPad Air. However the cells not being transparent it seems has nothing to do with it being modal. I was getting the same issue when using "show".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue but I'm not sure that this is a bug. For some reason setting the background color of the Cell in IB doesn't work on iPad.

Changing the cell code to this worked.

```
class testTableCell:UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var testTableCell: UILabel!

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
}
```

Has no one else had this problem?

Comment: So it looks like a bug that was introduced in ios7. See here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901394/uitableview-uitableviewcell-challenge-with-transparent-background-on-ipad-with.

I'm very surprised that Apple has let this slip.