# iOS Solid text over a background image and low alpha cell background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, background, alpha

How do I get the text in my cells to show as solid text while still fading the cell background so I can see the image behind?

I have the following in my ViewController:
`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Used to see the background image
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    cell.alpha=0.5; 
    cell.textLabel.alpha=1.0; 
}
```

The result is shown in the image where the background image can be seen through the text and cell background. I only want to see the image through the cell background and have the text solid.

Is there a way to set the text to have an alpha of 1.0 while the background is 0.5?

[app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgIJ4.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableView / UITableViewCell challenge with transparent background on iPad with iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901394/uitableview-uitableviewcell-challenge-with-transparent-background-on-ipad-with)

Comment: You set the entire sell alpha to 0.5, and the cell obviously includes its textLabel. I suppose you could try to add a solid-color subview to the cell with alpha 0.5, and the text as another subview with alpha 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this either in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `willDisplayCell`:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

Output:

[image]

Set the label text color as you normally would (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), and adjust the `colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5` to suit your needs.

Comment: The linked duplicate already covers this. Why not vote to close instead of posting an answer?

Comment: Because someone wants points obviously. :)

Comment: @HangarRash - meh... figured since the OP hadn't tried using `colorWithAlphaComponent` they probably wouldn't get that from the linked answer (which only referenced `clearColor`).